# How to negate a vowel condition using Regex in java

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to construct a Regex for a string which should have these following conditions:

1. It must contain at least one vowel.
2. It cannot contain three consecutive vowels or three consecutive consonants.
3. It cannot contain two consecutive occurrences of the same letter, except for 'ee' or 'oo'.

I'm not able to construct regex for 2nd and 3rd conditions.

e.g: 
bower - accepted,
appple - not accepted,
miiixer - not accepted,
hedding - not accepted,
feeding - accepted

Thanks in advance!

Edited:

My code:

```
Pattern ptn = Pattern.compile("((.*[A-Za-z0-9]*)(.*[aeiou|AEIOU]+)(.*[@#$%]).*)(.*[^a]{3}.*)");
Matcher mtch = ptn.matcher("zoggax");

if (mtch.find()) {
        return true;
    }
else
    return false;
```

Comment: Can you please show what you have tried so far?  We can augment it to help you out.

Comment: My advice.. Don't use regex.. :P. Regex should be used for *matching* conditions like x preceeded by 3 W's followed by 2 y's followed by 1 or more 9's

Comment: If you can create the automaton that represents your rules, then you can construct the regex.

Comment: Seems odd that it can't contain three consecutive consonants. Plenty of words do. "Construct" for instance.

Comment: @khelwood Not to mention three consecutive vowels. Onomatopoeia ends in 4.

Comment: @sid: i have edited the post with the code i was trying earlier. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following one should suit your needs:

```
(?=.*[aeiouy])(?!.*[aeiouy]{3})(?!.*[a-z&&[^aeiouy]]{3})(?!.*([a-z&&[^eo]])\\1).*
```

In Java:

```java
String regex = "(?=.*[aeiouy])(?!.*[aeiouy]{3})(?!.*[a-z&&[^aeiouy]]{3})(?!.*([a-z&&[^eo]])\\1).*";
System.out.println("bower".matches(regex));
System.out.println("appple".matches(regex));
System.out.println("miiixer".matches(regex));
System.out.println("hedding".matches(regex));
System.out.println("feeding".matches(regex));
```

Prints:

```
true
false
false
false
true
```

Explanation:

- `(?=.*[aeiouy])`: contains at least one vowel
- `(?!.*[aeiouy]{3})`: does not contain 3 consecutive vowels
- `(?!.*[a-z&&[^aeiouy]]{3})`: does not contain 3 consecutive consonants

  - `[a-z&&[^aeiouy]]`: any letter between `a` and `z` but none of `aeiouy`
- `(?!.*([a-z&&[^eo]])\1)`: does not contain 2 consecutive letters, except `e` and `o`

  - `[a-z&&[^eo]]`: any letter between `a` and `z`, but none of `eo`

See http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclassintersect.html.

Comment: This one works perfect! It would be helpful if you could brief about each regex groups that you have used. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should work for English under the assumption that 'y' is a non-vowel;

```
^(?!.*[aeiou]{3})(?!.*[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]{3})(?!.*([^eo])\1).*[aeiou]
```

Explanation:

- `^` fixes the match to the beginning of the string.
- `(?!.*[aeiou]{3})` checks that you can not find 3 consecutive vowels at any point after the current position in the string.  (Since this is immidiately after the ^ this checks the entire string).  It also does not advance the cursor.
- Non vowels are tested similarily.  This can be done in a prettier way if your regexp flavor supports set subtraction.  But I think Java does not do this.
- `(?!.*([^eo])\1)` checks that there are no occurence of a single character capture group, of characters other than e or o, which is followed by a copy of itself. Ie. no character other than e and o is repeated twice.
- `.*[aeiou]` looks for a vowel at some point in the string.

This regexp also assumes that the case-insensitive flag is set.  I think this is the default for java but I can be wrong about that.

It also is a regexp that will find a match in a string satisfying your criteria.  It will not necesarily match the whole string. - If this is needed add `.*$` to the end of the regexp.

Comment: Also under the assumption that the string is in lower case.

Comment: Great regex, but somehow 'feeding' is not passing this test.

Comment: @khelwood Not quite, I assumed that the case insesitive flag is set.  Will update answer to include.

Comment: @Sid, "feeding" does match this pattern.

Comment: I understand, but feeding should pass as per the question.  The third condition clearly states that.

Comment: @khelwood - Nope. The *entire* String has to match and it doesn't..So java Regex engine screams

Comment: @TheLostMind That depends on which function you use to test.

Comment: @Taemyr - Well, I am using `matches` which one do you propose?

Comment: @TheLostMind `find` looks for non-complete matches.  I have also added a description on how to make the regexp match the whole string to the answer.

Comment: @Taemyr - That was my point.. we have to match the *entire* string :P

Comment: @Taemyr: thanks for your reply. please see the edited post, i am using with Pattern, Matcher. Also, your code works great for some sample inputs, but breaks for inputs like "zoggax", "wiinq". Thanks!

Comment: @TheNerd ? It rejects the examples you provide, which it should because of the double g in zoggax and the double i in wiinq.  If you enter the regexp as a string you will need to escape the \.

Answer (score 0):

If my hunch is correct that you meant to say ***"three consecutive occurrences of the same letter"*** (looking at your examples) then you can simply say *"`e` and `o` may not occur **thrice**, everything else may not occur **twice**"*, like so:

```
^(?=.*[aeiouy].*)(?!.*([eo])\1\1.*)(?!.*([a-df-np-z])\2.*).*$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/viSZbVdkUOTtSFIE), Key is that a letter occuring thrice is *also* occuring twice.